# Error when converting String to DateTime: System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, timeofday

I am trying to compare two dates in C#. One is a sunset date and one is the current date. I am trying to determine whether it's after or before sunset.
I have two dates like that:

1. 2021-12-02 16:19 (Current Date)
2. 05:55:50 PM (Sunset Date)

I have been trying to compare them this way:

```
var currentTime = DateTime.ParseExact(Weather.location.localtime, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).TimeOfDay;
var sunsetTime = DateTime.ParseExact(SunriseSunset.results.sunset, "hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).TimeOfDay;

bool sunStillUp = currentTime < sunsetTime;
```

I know that the error means that the given dates are in incorrect format, however I cannot see how..

Weather.location.localtime is this (getting data from an api):

[image]

And SunriseSunset.results.sunset is this (getting data from an api):

[image]

Comment: What **date** do you think `05:55:50 PM` is?

Comment: Allright @HardCode, addded a date in front of it: now it's `2021-12-02 05:55:50 PM`.        Then the code is : `var sunsetTime = DateTime.ParseExact(sunset, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).TimeOfDay;` But it still does not work

Comment: `DateTime.ParseExact("2021-12-02 05:55:50 PM", "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` works fine for me. But the last screenshot shows that you may get a 1-digit hour, so you probably should use `yyyy-MM-dd h:m:s tt`

Comment: You're right, with the yyyy-MM-dd h:m:s tt format it works! Thanks for pointing that out!